# Is there a way to switch files in split screen?

Tags: split

I've been reading a lot about split screens in vim, but actually getting your cursor over to the other document is still a problem.

You can create a vertical split screen with `:vsplit <file-name>`, and a blank horizontal split screen with `ctrl+w n`, and a horizontal help split screen with `:help`, but none of the recommendations i've read for alternating your cursor between files actually work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is there in `:help window-move-cursor`, it also helps to at least skim `:h window`.

```
4. Moving cursor to other windows           *window-move-cursor*

CTRL-W <Down>                   *CTRL-W_<Down>*
CTRL-W CTRL-J                   *CTRL-W_CTRL-J* *CTRL-W_j*
CTRL-W j    Move cursor to Nth window below current one.  Uses the cursor
        position to select between alternatives.

CTRL-W <Up>                 *CTRL-W_<Up>*
CTRL-W CTRL-K                   *CTRL-W_CTRL-K* *CTRL-W_k*
CTRL-W k    Move cursor to Nth window above current one.  Uses the cursor
        position to select between alternatives.

CTRL-W <Left>                   *CTRL-W_<Left>*
CTRL-W CTRL-H                   *CTRL-W_CTRL-H*
CTRL-W <BS>                 *CTRL-W_<BS>* *CTRL-W_h*
CTRL-W h    Move cursor to Nth window left of current one.  Uses the
        cursor position to select between alternatives.

CTRL-W <Right>                  *CTRL-W_<Right>*
CTRL-W CTRL-L                   *CTRL-W_CTRL-L* *CTRL-W_l*
CTRL-W l    Move cursor to Nth window right of current one.  Uses the
        cursor position to select between alternatives.

CTRL-W w                    *CTRL-W_w* *CTRL-W_CTRL-W*
CTRL-W CTRL-W   Without count: move cursor to window below/right of the
        current one.  If there is no window below or right, go to
        top-left window.
        With count: go to Nth window (windows are numbered from
        top-left to bottom-right).  To obtain the window number see
        |bufwinnr()| and |winnr()|.  When N is larger than the number
        of windows go to the last window.
```

Comment: "ctrl+w <direction>" does accomplish what i was looking for, however, i'm using stack exchanges rather than the help pages because with the help pages you have to already know the exact wording for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to switch between panes or buffers?  You can always cycle through buffers with :bn for next buffer.  Or you can go directly to a buffer with :b#, so :b1 goes to buffer 1.  There are plugins you can use to list the buffers and their buffer numbers.

If you just want to switch between panes, think of CTRL+W as putting vim into window navigation mode and then use hjkl to move in the same directions you would use those keys for moving around inside the buffer.  If you would rather have different key bindings, you can always create a custom keymap.  But, IMHO, it's better to learn the keybindings from vim so you can use the default configuration anywhere.

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious that i was talking about windows, not buffers, but thanks for commenting anyways. ```Ctrl + W``` does allow me to switch panes when i'm at the edge of a document, yet i wish there was some alternative to this because i typically would want to switch to the far left side of the pane instead of having to think of it that way.

Comment: @thinksinbinary there are more than just C-w [hjkl]; for example, C-w p is "previous window"

Comment: @thinksinbinary adding on to that, you can get to the left-most pane with `Ctrl + w 1 w`. If a count is given, it will take you to the corresponding window. The windows are numbered in increasing order, starting from the top left most window